# Evaluate the following Riemann Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha(x) = 3[x]$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{2}{\alpha\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right) \mathrm{d}\alpha(x)}$$

Attempt: If I apply the same idea of evaluating R-S integrals w.r.t jump functions, I get that  $$\int_{0}^{2}{\alpha\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right) \mathrm{d}\alpha(x)} = \alpha\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)\cdot [\alpha(1)-\alpha(0)] = 3\cdot 3 =9$$

My questions would be :

(1) Evaluating the integral in the above fashion relies on the theorem which says that when $f$ is continuous and $\alpha(x)$ is the monotone jump function then $$\int_{a}^{b}{f \mathrm{d}\alpha} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{c_n f(s_n)}$$ where $c_n$ are the values of the function $\alpha(x)$ and $s_n$ are the points at which the jump occurs. For the above integral $$f = \alpha\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)$$ is not continuous, so the theorem would fail. **Is the continuity of $f$ required**? In the proof the continuity is used to determine that $f\in \mathbb{R}(\alpha)$

(2) If the theorem fails, and I cannot apply it to the above integral, any other ideas? I tried using integration by parts, however it circles back to the issue of (1) above.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well,, in the interval $[0,2]$, your function $\alpha$ has a jump at $1$ and at $2$, but not at $0$.  The integrand is continuous at both those points, which is all that is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem can be stated in a weaker form.

> Let $[a,b]$ be an interval. Let $f,\alpha:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$. Define $\alpha$ as follows $$\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}  \alpha(a) &a\leq x<c\\\alpha(b)&c< x\leq b\\\alpha(c)&x=c\end{cases}$$

Let $f,\alpha$ be defined in such a way that at least one of $\alpha,f$ is continuous on the left of $c$ and one on the right of $c$. Then $f\in\mathscr R(\alpha)$ and $$\int_a^b fd\alpha=f(c)\cdot\left(\alpha(c^+)-\alpha(c^-)\right)$$

In particular, as it is pointed out in the comments, if $f$ is continuous at the jumps and $\alpha$ has left or right jumps, the integral exists and is what you claim.